# How to pass API URI as a variable in vbs script?

Tags: vbscript

I have Vb script for run Put request. I have URL. that URL is saved in the excel and I'm saving that url as variable and pass that url to put command.

Example vURL: https://example.com/api/

I have already tried different arguments and quotations mark but it doesn't work.

```
Dim args, vURL
Set args = WScript.Arguments

'vURL = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1
'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

vURL = args(0)
MsgBox vURL
Dim http: Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim url: url = vURL

With http
  Call .Open("PUT", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("XAPI-KEY", "")
  Call .Send("")
End With

If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then

  response = http.responseText
  MsgBox response
Else

  response = http.responseText
  MsgBox response
End If
```

If I put the vURL without Quotes. Response comes as empty but it should have some kind of response.

If I put the vURL in the quotations, response comes back as is not authorize protocal.

Code works fine when I hard code the URL in.

Comment: Please share the relevant part of the rest VBA code which is used to launch the VBScript. Why do you need to run PUT request in such way within separate VBS? Why not just run it in VBA?

Comment: We are using Automation Anywhere to do pass in a vURL variable. This is vbs script because automation anywhere only can run the vbs script. I should have clarify that. We are not using VBA .I update the question to say vbs script

Comment: `MsgBox vURL` does this produce the expected result?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes, MsgBox vURl gives me correct URL that I need to pass to .open("PUT", url)

Comment: Compare the hard coded URL which works fine and URL from argument. Some whitespace chars might be added. Add after `MsgBox vURL` the following lines: `vHardCoded = "https://example.com/api/"`, `MsgBox vHardCoded = vURL`, `MsgBox Trim(vHardCoded) = Trim(vURL)`, `MsgBox Len(vHardCoded)`,  `MsgBox Len(vURL)`.

Comment: @omegastripes MsgBox Trim(vHardCoded) = Trim(vURL) was false. Length for Hardcode was 62 and Length vURL was 68.

Comment: That help me solve the issue. Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer for your question to help others?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @omegastripes for help. I was able to resolve the issue by comparing the length of hard coded URL and vURL. Length wasn't matching.